# UITableView didSeectRowAtIndexPath causing EXC_BAD_ERROR

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I am trying to create a simple UITableView with Xcode 4.3 and SDK 5.1. In the older SDK's I have not received the following error so I'm a bit confused as to what is happening despite checking the Profiler and also NSZombie.

in my .h file

```
NSMutableArray *fruits;
```

in my .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    fruits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [fruits addObject:@"Apples"];
    [fruits addObject:@"Bananas"];
    [fruits addObject:@"Oranges"];
    [fruits addObject:@"Kiwi Fruit"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [fruits release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [fruits count]);
    return [fruits count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FruitsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *title = [fruits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedOption = [fruits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedOption);
}
```

Whenever I select a fruit, I get the EXC_BAD_ERROR and the output shows "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance"

I had brief look at ARC and thought this may be the issue with memory management so I removed the dealloc but it still throws the exception. What am I missing from this simple example?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks perfect. I guess ARC is disabled since you have autorelease and such even though you mentioned it.
One thing I would check is delegate of the UITableView to see if it is properly set to your view controller on xib.

Comment: I have checked the delegates are set properly. It still just throws the error in @autoreleasepool { return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); } in the app delegate.

Comment: hmm I see. I actually copy&pasted your code and create one project. It works just fine in Xcode 4.2 with SDK 5.1. I have no clue then

Comment: I just did the same and it worked so there must be something wrong elsewhere. I've created a simple login, when successful it pushes a DefaultViewController onto the stack, in this DefaultViewController is where this simple UITableView sits. I'm not sure why this would throw the exception, when in the new project i created to test the uitableview it doesnt as the code is the same.

Comment: ok I found the problem. when i created the DefaultViewController from the parent controller, i set it as autorelease before pushing it on to the stack. I'm not sure why this would throw the exception but the keyword you mentioned was autorelease which helped.

Comment: oh I see. I didn't think anything other than tableview but glad my comment helped!